# show $\sum_{k=0}^n {k \choose i} = {n+1 \choose i+1}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

show for n $\geq i \geq 1 : \sum_{k=0}^n {k \choose i} = $ ${n+1} \choose {i+1}$

i show this with induction:

for n=i=1: ${1+1} \choose {1+1}$ = $2 \choose 2$ = 1 = $0 \choose 1$ + $1 \choose 1$ = $\sum_{k=0}^1 {k \choose 1}$

now let $\sum_{k=0}^n {k \choose i} = $ ${n+1} \choose {i+1}$

for n+1: ${n+1+1} \choose {i+1}$ = $n+1 \choose i$ + $n+1 \choose i$ = $ n+1 \choose i$ + $\sum_{k=0}^n {k \choose i} = \sum_{k=0}^{n+1} {k \choose i}  $

Is this the right way ?

Comment: Yes.it is true.

Answer (score 1):

Induction on $n$ will work, but your argument got into trouble (perhaps only typo trouble) with indices. We want to show that if the result is true for $n=w$, then it is true for $n=w+1$.
So our induction assumption is that 
$$\sum_{k=0}^w\binom{k}{i}=\binom{w+1}{i+1},$$
and we want to show that
$$\sum_{k=0}^{w+1}\binom{k}{i}=\binom{w+2}{i+1},$$

Consider the sum
$$\sum_{k=0}^{w+1}\binom{k}{i}.\tag{1}$$
This is equal to 
$$\sum_{k=0}^{w}\binom{k}{i}+\binom{w+1}{i}.\tag{2}$$
By the induction assumption, we have
$$\sum_{k=0}^w \binom{k}{i}=\binom{w+1}{i+1}.$$
Thus (2) is equal to
$$\binom{w+1}{i+1}+\binom{w+1}{i}.\tag{3}$$
By the Pascal Identity, (3) is equal to
$$\binom{w+2}{i+1},$$
which is what we wanted to show.

Comment: In the line between equations 2 and 3, you meant $$\sum_{k = 0}^{\color{red}{w}} \binom{k}{i} = \binom{w + 1}{i + 1}$$

Comment: Yes, thank you, I don't know how $2$ ended up as the upper limit. Perhaps because it is close to $w$ on the keyboard, and I am having a little wine while making dinner.

Answer (score 0):

We can also use the recurrence from Pascal's Triangle and telescoping series:
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{k}{i}
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\left[\binom{k+1}{i+1}-\binom{k}{i+1}\right]\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\binom{k}{i+1}-\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{k}{i+1}\\
&=\binom{n+1}{i+1}-\binom{0}{i+1}\\
&=\binom{n+1}{i+1}
\end{align}
$$